# What is happening with my pc?

Tags: windows, boot

I turned my PC on and while Windows was booting A long beep sound was made and the screen turned into an almost command-line like enviroment and flashed a whole bunch of garbled text and ascii symbols, then when I restarted it said that "Windows could not load the Dynamic Enviroment, press any key to restart".

What issue is causing this and how can I fix it?

Edit: The beep is NOT coming from the POST, as it is during the boot process for windows.

Comment: What is your motherboards vendor and model? Was it only one long beep or some other pattern like one short and one long beep? Please do not respond in the comments but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1377706/edit) your question.

Comment: Please try to replicate the problem by booting into a LiveUSB with Linux, https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html https://www.lifewire.com/create-uefi-bootable-linux-mint-usb-2202084 and if you are able to run Linux OK, then try to boot into Windows Safe Mode https://support.eset.com/kb2268 . Please click on [edit] and advise the result. You could also remove and reseat the memory modules, the first step in hardware troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

A long Beep when you boot, it should be caused by computer hardware issue.

On startup, computers perform a Power on Self Test, commonly referred to as a POST. If the POST is failed, the motherboard will emit beeps of different meanings. BIOSes from different motherboard manufacturers also have different beeps.

Check your motherboard's vendor and model, and refer to this document to narrow down what's wrong with your hardware. [enter link description here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afzy)

You could to replace the issue hardware or contact with hardware manufactures.